# Spring Boot Dependency with Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-3

I have a `Spring 3` dependent project which I am using in my latest spring boot project

I am facing issues with auto wiring 
my spring 3 project has a Gateway Interface (`IAccountGateway`)

I am facing an issue like

```
Description:<br>
 <br>Field iAccountGateway in
 com.rvi.service.common.impl.RegistrationService required a bean of type
 'com.rvi.jms.gateway.IAccountGateway' that could not be found. <br><br>Action:<br>
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.rvi.jms.gateway.IAccountGateway'
in your configuration.
```

when I put debug in my spring project I got log something like below

```
Registered injected element on class <br><br>
[com.rvi.service.common.impl.RegistrationService]:
AutowiredFieldElement for private com.rvi.jms.gateway.IAccountGateway
com.rvi.service.common.impl.RegistrationService.iAccountGateway
```

Comment: `'com.rvi.jms.gateway.IAccountGateway` Bean not found. Means you have to create a bean of it and provide it for DI.

Comment: @MehrajMalik Yes.. why I need to create a bean? my dependent project should (spring 3) should take care of this instead of me <br> if i need to create how can i create the bean? and where i can create a bean ?since IAccountGateway is a Interface

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `IAccountGateway` is an interface, then, you need to implement it and define as a Spring Bean with `@Component` annotation (there are also [other](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection) annotations that have similar effect).

**IAccountGateway.java**

```
public interface IAccountGateway {

    // ..

}
```

**AccountGatewayImpl.java** (the IAccountGateway implementation)

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AccountGatewayImpl implements IAccountGateway {

    // ..

}
```

**Autowiring the field:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Clazz {

    @Autowired
    IAccountGateway iAccountGateway;

    // ..
}
```

See [Spring Boot Reference on Spring Beans and Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection)